# Windows console appears when running Win32 application

Tags: winapi, netbeans, console, codeblocks

When you compile a Win32 program using Visual studio I don't remember there was a console appears then the window shows up. In Code blocks and Netbeans the windows console appears when you run the program and the application's window appears. Should I care about this or there is some missing configuration ? I mean is there a way to disable the console ? Note that I started a C++ project in Netbeans and Win32 GUI project in Code blocks.

Comment: You are compiling a console subsystem application. You need to target the Windows subsystem, aka the GUI subsystem. The setting will be different for each IDE. Now that you know the search terms, you should be able to work the rest out.

Comment: Done for codeblocks! Netbeans' turn. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Also, be aware that a program built in debug-mode using C::B will show a console window. This is remedied simply by selecting Release and re-building.

Comment: But I changed the build target into GUI and there is no console. I even ran the program from Windows Explorer and there is no console.

Comment: @enhzflep That doesn't sound right at all. The console window is determined by the target subsystem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it may well not, but it is a matter of fact. Creating a project in C::B creates two build-targets. The Release one has symbols stripped -O2 selected etc and, _for win32 targets_ it has the Window Subsystem chosen. A debug build on the other hand, has neither of the aforementioned flags set and also comes with Console application set. So really, we're saying the same thing from different perspectives, with different target audiences and with different levels of knowledge of the tool being discussed, that's all. :)

Comment: @enhzflep OK. That surprises me. Seems like a shocking design flaw if you ask me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it's rather convenient in my experience. Many times, firing-up the debugger, whether it be GDB or VS's built-in one, is overkill and an oversight can be immediately discovered with a judicially placed printf. However, one is free to queue remarks about "free" and "value for money". :)

Comment: @enhzflep If they wanted to do that then a call to AllocConsole is the way. Changing the subsystem has other consequences.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Your point is correct for Netbeans. I added the switch -mwindows to the linker and when I switched to release no console appeared. Although on both configuration with the switch added it will run without a console from windows explorer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks, it seems I've some more reading to do on the weekend. I don't recall having been told before that such a change to the subsystem would have other detrimental consequences.

Answer (score 1):

In Code::Blocks, right-click on the project name > Properties > Build Targets and change the "Type" drop-down menu from Console Application to GUI Application.

In Netbeans, Either switch to Release mode, or right click on project name > Properties > Linker and under Additional Options add the option `-mwindows`. Notice if you run the program as Debug the console windows will appear but running under explorer you will not see the console.